# force juju to run deployment again

Tags: juju, maas

I was deploying `openstack` bundle using `juju` and `maas` and it failed. So i found the problem on `maas` configuration and made a fix there.
but when I try to deploy the bundle again juju says:

`No changes to apply.`

How I can enforce it to make deployment again??!

I'm going to destroy controller and bootstrap it again!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the model and try again. This will remove all the machines in that model.